# Show that $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\times [0,2\pi)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I need to show that $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\times [0,2\pi)$.  This is fairly intuitive; recognizing that $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of rotations, take $r\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$.  Then if $v_1$ is an initial vector prior to a rotation and $v_2=rv_1$ the cross product $v_1\times v_2$ is an orthogonal rotation axis which is stabilized by a rotation $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ through the plane created by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

However, I need something more formal and rigorous than an intuitive description of the problem.  Any hints in that regard will be appreciated.

Comment: $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is compact. Did you mean it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times S^1$?

Comment: $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, but $\mathbb{RP}^2\times [0,2\pi)$ is not. So they aren't homeomorphic. Have you misread the question?

Comment: $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\times S^1$ either, but that's harder to see.

Comment: The actual topology of $SO_3(\Bbb{R})$ is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Topology).

Comment: What he basically meant to ask was that $SO_3(\Bbb R)$ forms a circle bundle over $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$, i.e, a fibre bundle whose base is $\Bbb R \Bbb P^2$ and whose fibers are homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: @Shalop: unfortunately (or maybe not $\ddot{\smile}$), the rest of us aren't mind-readers. So we can only respond to the question asked.

Comment: I double checked and I've copied the question correctly.  However, this is only part of the question.  The next part says to conclude from this part that $\pi_1(SO_3(\mathbb{R}))\cong \pi_1(SL_3(\mathbb{R}))\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Does that provide enough context to figure out what was meant.  Unfortunately I think it's to late to ask for clarification.

Comment: If you've been asked to show that $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\times [0,2\pi)$, then you've been asked to prove something false.  The next part doesn't help me see what might have been meant in the first part, but others may do better at second-guessing the intentions of an incorrectly posed question (see Shalop's comment perhaps). [I'd be interested to hear the outcome.]